# Xcode 5.0.1 and BBUncrustify, not on xcode menus

Tags: xcode, plugins

Anyone having issues seeing the plugin for BBUncrustify and XCode 5.0.1?  Menus show up fine on XCode 4.6.3, but not on XCode 5.0.1

https://github.com/benoitsan/BBUncrustifyPlugin-Xcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to delete the old 4.6.3 target in the users XCODE directory and then rebuild the new one and then restart XCODE 5.x (maybe > 1) and then it works.